# sum of all previous columns in a row in last cell

Tags: jquery

I have this Code

[image]

And i want in Last Column Cell in current row have sum of all previous td cells. *On Page Load, without use of classes if it is possible, for all rows in table.

For example

```
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>3</td> <!-- this is empty cell which will on page load filled with SUM value !-->
</tr>
```

How can i do that ? Thank you

Comment: Select all the rows, loop those, select all the tds in each, loop those and create the row total, add the row total to the last td. Nested `each`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('tr').find('td:last').text(function() {
    return $(this).siblings().map(function() { return parseInt($(this).text(), 10); }).get().reduce(function(x, y) { return x + y });
});
```

Find the last `td` in each `tr`, then set the `text` by getting the `text` of each sibling `td` (using `map`), then sum the resulting array using `reduce()`.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sttdds7c/1/)

Comment: But can i say that i want sibling only from 5'th td ? I know sibling can use prev css selector but im not able to add classes to that table.. its some handsome table plugin and i cant figure how i can add classes to that rows.

Comment: I tried play with Index but im not able to use it properly.. return $(this).siblings().map(function() 
        { 
            if ( $(this).index(this) > 5 ) {return parseInt($(this).text(),10); }
            else {return 0;}
        }

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to get a list/array of all your `td`'s then total up the contents. i.e.

```
var tds = $('.htCore td');
var total = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
  total += parseInt(tds[i].html());
}

$('.htCore td:last-child').html(total);
```

This works assuming you have no strings/text in your td's, if you do then you'll need:

```
var tds = $('.htCore td');
var total = 0;
var content = '';

for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
  content = parseInt(tds[i].html();

  if(!isNaN(content)){
    total += content;
  }
}

$('.htCore td:last-child').html(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is probably a bad idea. Those `td` are nodes displaying text, and it's a good idea to keep your logic separate from the representation.

That being said, you could do something like this:

```
var total = 0;

// Get an array of all the elements, and add their contents to total
$('td').map(function(_,v){total += +v.innerText;})

// Set the content of the last td to be total
$('td:last-child').text(total);
```

### Explanation

We're calling a function on all of the `<td>`. This function just casts the text content of the `<td>` to a number, and adds it to our `total` variable.

Then we just write the value of `total` to the last `<td>` as specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can utilize the looping of jquery `.each()` in tandem with a class to determine the last td (`.sum`) where the sum should be placed, as shown below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table tr').each(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      if (!$(this).hasClass('sum')){
        var num = parseInt($(this).text());
        sum = sum + num;
      }
    });
    $(this).find('.sum').text(sum);
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td class="sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="sum"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this code will work for all rows in the table (or if you want it for select rows, just add a class to the rows you want this summation to apply to)